# Converting milliseconds date to normal date

Tags: php, date

I got the following format of date from an API:

```
1468102548
```

I'm trying to convert this date to a normal human readable format, however I can't get it to work.

Here's what I've tried so far:

```
$creation_date = "1468102548";

$input1 = $creation_date / 1000;

$newDate_creation_date = date("Y-m-d", $input1); // Output: 1970-01-17 (It's not right)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That timestamp is not in milliseconds so dividing it by 1000 is skewing your date.

```
$creation_date = new DateTime('@1468102548');
echo $creation_date->format('Y-m-d'); // Outputs 2016-07-09
```

[Demo](https://eval.in/630447)

Comment: `@1468102548` that is bizarre to use the `@` here. Well, it's "bizarre" to me anyway ;-)

Comment: I don't know why the `@` was chosen but I guess they needed some way to indicate the value is a timestamp and not a string.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Boss, do u use Linux or Windows ?

Comment: @HendraNucleo My test machine's on Windows but my working servers are on \*NIX; why do you ask?

Comment: @Fred-ii- Fedo, cent, Deb?